# Java how to improve the code of the custom validation form in order to be more legible

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I'm trying to create a validator for a form. I want to check if all the information is completed correctly.
I have a form in which the user needs to insert inspected items. For that, I will have on the form a dynamic number of lines and all of them will be stored in the InspectedItemCreationDto list as InspectedItemDto objects. It's not mandatory to fill all of the lines but, when the user starts to insert information about one item, he will need to fill all the information till the end of the line in order to not have any Null or Black value stored in the properties of the InspectedItemDto object.

I managed to obtain something but it looks a little messy.

```
    public boolean isValid(InspectedItemCreationDto values, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    for (InspectedItemDto i : values.getInspectedItems()) {
        if (!((Stream.of(i.getItem(), i.getDescription(), i.getSerialLot()).allMatch(String::isBlank) &&
                Stream.of(i.getWoNumber(), i.getTotalPieces(), i.getOkPieces(), i.getNokPieces()).allMatch(Objects::isNull)) ||
                (Stream.of(i.getItem(), i.getDescription(), i.getSerialLot()).noneMatch(String::isBlank) &&
                        Stream.of(i.getWoNumber(), i.getTotalPieces(), i.getOkPieces(), i.getNokPieces()).noneMatch(Objects::isNull)))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I attached I picture with the form, maybe it will help you to have a better understanding of what I'm doing :D

I tried to find the best way to resolve this problem, and with my current knowledge, this is all I could get :D. I'm trying to learn how to write code as correctly as possible and I hope that I will learn something new with this occasion.

[Form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfq8z.png)

Thank you,

Comment: sorry what's the problem? that the code in your opinion is not readable?

Comment: It is readable but i was thinking that can be improve, maybe writen in a easier way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1):

JSR303 is your best option most probably. You are using Spring based on your tags. Please take a look at this guide for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#validation-beanvalidation

You could annotate your class that represents the items of the collection and also the root object if you want validate the number of items min/max etc.